converting use case diagram to an use case template
I am new to UML and have a problem. I am trying to model a system where a teacher can develop an assignment paper and use an LLM to generate answers to make a more robust paper. later, the moderator views the assignment paper and sends feedback; accordingly, the teacher will modify the assignment paper.

I am converting the use case diagram to use case templates. I have given one such use case template below of the use case generate answers. I would appreciate it if I could know if the preconditions is too detailed in terms of best practice guidelines in software engineering. The intended audience is a professor with over 10 years of industry experience.



Use case name
Generate answer




Actors
Teacher, LLM


Preconditions
The Teacher must be registered and logged in.The Teacher is in the create new assignment tab The Teacher has filled out the text input question


Postconditions
An answer to the question are generated.


Trigger
The teacher clicks on the “generate” button


Main Flow
1. The system generates a prompt using the question entered by the teacher  2. The LLM analyses the question and generates an answer 3.    The system displays the answer to the question


Assumptions
The LLM suggests relevant answers The LLM does not give an error instead of the answer




youve asked this 3 times now. it sounds like homework#

No, it is that I am developing a system for research, I have created the system, but I am struggling with the UML part, and my professor is giving me a really tough time, I drew an activity diagram, and he bombarded me that is why I turned to this

"Give me some (general) feedback" questions don't work well with the Q&A format of this site, and definitely not with our community here. "I am not confident about " is not a clear problem statement. However, if you would ask specifically about the "Preconditions" section of you template, what points exactly you not confident with and what you are looking for, then this might become an answerable question.

... moreover, when your audience is a single person you know (but we don't), it is most effective when you ask that person directly what he/she is expecting from you.

surely if you have a literal professor teaching you, just ask them

No he is my research supervisor he is bad tempered, and I am on the edge of keeping or loosing my PhD


I would appreciate it if I could know if the preconditions is too detailed

Yes, your preconditions are too detailed. This comes primarily from your assumptions on a particular UI being used.
At the point in the project where use-cases are being created, no decisions have yet been made on the look and feel of the user interface, or even the type of user interface. So, use-cases should be written to be agnostic of that.
Another improvement would be to replace your assumptions with alternative/exceptional flows that should be taken if the stated assumption turns out to be false.
An improved version of your use-case template is:



Use case name
Generate answer




Actors
Teacher, LLM


Preconditions
The Teacher must be logged in.The Teacher has provided a question text


Postconditions
An answer to the question are generated.


Trigger
The teacher requests to generate answers


Main Flow
1. The system generates a prompt using the question entered by the teacher  2.    The LLM analyses the question and generates an answer 3.   The system displays the answer to the question


Exceptional flows
1. If the suggested answers are not relevant, the Teacher can restart the use-case 2. If the LLM gives an error instead of the answer  2.1. The system displays the error



